# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "user/get_notifications" does not contain "{userid}"

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am fetching JSON data from api using Retrofit 2. But when I am running the app, it is showing an error that

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "user/get_notifications" does not contain "{userid}".
```

I have not used `userid` in my code and have no idea how to remove the error.
Here is my code:

```html
public class noti_sec{
 @SerializedName("id")
    String id;
    @SerializedName("type")
    String type;

    @SerializedName("text")
    String noti_msg;
    @SerializedName("for_userid")
    String for_userid;
    @SerializedName("from_userid")
    String from_userid;
    @SerializedName("for_image")
    String for_image;
    @SerializedName("seen")
    String seen;
    @SerializedName("username")
    String username;
    @SerializedName("firstname")
    String firstname;
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    String lastname;
    @SerializedName("imgname")
    String imgname;






    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getNoti_msg() {
        return noti_msg;
    }

    public void setNoti_msg(String noti_msg) {
        this.noti_msg = noti_msg;
    }

    public String getFor_userid() {
        return for_userid;
    }

    public void setFor_userid(String for_userid) {
        this.for_userid = for_userid;
    }

    public String getFrom_userid() {
        return from_userid;
    }

    public void setFrom_userid(String from_userid) {
        this.from_userid = from_userid;
    }

    public String getFor_image() {
        return for_image;
    }

    public void setFor_image(String for_image) {
        this.for_image = for_image;
    }

    public String getSeen() {
        return seen;
    }

    public void setSeen(String seen) {
        this.seen = seen;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getImgname() {
        return imgname;
    }

    public void setImgname(String imgname) {
        this.imgname = imgname;
    }

}
```

Other one:

```html
public class full_noti_sec {


    @SerializedName("status")
    String status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<noti_sec> data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<noti_sec> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<noti_sec> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

and the interface one:

```html
public interface notiIterface {
    @GET("user/get_notifications")
    Call<full_noti_sec> getNotification(@Path("userid") String userid, @Path("session") String session);
}
```

Comment: @Path("userid") - this should be removed/checked

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

From the endpoint URL: http://chikoop.com/api/index.php/user/get_notifications/ it looks like

1. It is not expecting a `userid` field
2. It is expecting `sessionid` somehow, probably in request body, authorization  header etc. But NOT as `@Path` in the `getNotification()` method.

Please refer to the appropriate API documentation.

---

Double check the source from where you are learning/referencing retrofit.

```
public interface notiIterface {
    @GET("user/get_notifications")
    Call<full_noti_sec> getNotification(@Path("userid") String userid, @Path("session") String session);
}
```

Clearly in your `getNotifications` method you are referencing `userid` and `session` `@Path` variables but the endpoint for your GET method does not contain those.

**NOTE:** I am just **assuming**, if valid, it could look something like this:

```
@GET("{session}/user/{userid}/get_notifications")
```

Comment: Yes I did, to edit the endpoint that I'm assuming would be the correct one.

Comment: Please paste the URL of the endpoint you are trying to access.

Comment: It seems you don't really need any of the arguments in getNotifications method.

Comment: i am using retrofit and i uses userid and seesion to reach to this url

Comment: @nickymanai Check my updated answer. You also need to update the question with edited code and error that you are getting now. If there is anything unrelated to the current method or error, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already not described in your interface a method signature with empty path param (rather just request params) then it would look out that your HTTP calls should always be in the format of "/user/get_notifications/{userid}/{session}". Did you try with that URL using HTTP GET